# What is the default transaction isolation level for SQL Server with ADO.NET?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions, ado.net

What is the default transaction isolation level for SQL Server with ADO.NET? I am using a default installation of SQL Server and just the normal System.Data.SqlClient classes.

Comment: @Neolisk: Things are often more complex than they seem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851415/sql-server-isolation-level-leaks-across-pooled-connections

Comment: Just curious about the fragment of your question which specifically mentions `with ADO.NET`? I believe irrespective of the provider w.r.t. the client side programming world (Java, .Net, Python etc) the default is driven by the database engine and NOT the provider. So the default isolation level for SQL Server should remain same irrespective of whether you are using ADO.NET or any other client side provider to connect to a SQL Server database. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For other settings, there are differences between the defaults for ADO.NET and SQL Server Management Studio. So that's not really a safe assumption.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> READ COMMITTED is the default isolation level for the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.

Source:

- [Customizing Transaction Isolation Level @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175909.aspx).

Here is how it compares to other isolation levels:

- [Transaction Isolation Levels @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The MSDN documentation for `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()` also states `Read committed`

> ... To reset the isolation level to the default (READ COMMITTED) ...

- [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer by hkf gives the correct answer for transactions started *manually* with `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()`. Here, the default level is **ReadCommitted**.

However, this is not the only way to start a new transaction in ADO.NET: Transactions can also be created *automatically* by using the classes from the `System.Transactions` namespace, in particular, by creating a `TransactionScope`.

Contrary to transactions started manually, transactions created by the `System.Transactions` infrastructure (and, thus, by a `TransactionScope`) are **Serializable**.

See below link for more information:

- [IsolationLevel Enumeration @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).