# Setting SQL Default Transaction Isolation Level

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, isolation-level

I want to have an application where the isolation level would ALWAYS be SNAPSHOT. If I want to use stored procedures for the application, how would I go about ensuring that the transaction level stays set to SNAPSHOT?

Every time I closed the connection, would the next connection not default to the MSSQL Server default(READ COMMITTED)?

Basically its seems like I would be best off adding a 'SET TRANSACTION' command at the top off all my stored procedures.

Also, it seems that there is no way to set a 'DEFAULT' isolation level for a database, is this true?

EDIT**

I am aware of the default transaction level! Please re-read the question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default transaction isolation level for SQL Server with ADO.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003026/what-is-the-default-transaction-isolation-level-for-sql-server-with-ado-net)

Comment: @IvanStarostin Please re-read the question. I am fully aware of the default transaction level.

Comment: Please explain down vote...... help me improve this question

Comment: I think what you're talking about is in the database properties, e.g. Allow Snapshot Isolation = True and Is Read Committed Snapshot On = True.

Comment: @JacobBarnes Yes! And those can be set for the database, however it seems that the transaction isolation level for a new connection defaults to READ COMMITTED, is that true and is there any way around it?

Comment: Not if you're enforcing it at the database level.

Comment: @JacobBarnes So it can only be enforced at the transaction level, and therefore would be limited to the open connection?

Comment: No, READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION will apply to every single transaction.

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/snapshot-isolation-level-in-sql-server-what-why-and-how-part-1.html

Comment: @JacobBarnes Thank you, that is what i was looking for. If you want to write up an aanswer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION will achieve the results you're wanting. You can enable this setting in the database properties.