# SqlDependency subscription not working when using IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted in (unrelated?) Transaction

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, sql-server-2012, sqldependency

I've managed to get SqlDependency working, but only as long as I do not use `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited` in what I thought was a SQL transaction unrelated to the SqlDependency.

When I use `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` in the transaction (heavily commented below) the SqlDependency subscription fails with an immediate `OnChange` notification of:

```
sqlNotificationEventArgs.Info = "Isolation";
sqlNotificationEventArgs.Source = "Statement";
sqlNotificationEventArgs.Type = "Subscribe";
```

When I remove the IsolationLevel everything works as expected (well, the isolation isn't right, of course).

Here is my relevant code:

```
private static string connString = "the connection string";
[MTAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
    while(true)
    {
        using (var context = new LinqDataContext(connString))
        {
            var conn = context.Connection;
            conn.Open();
            /***********************************************************************/
            /* Remove `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` and the SqlDependency works */
            /***********************************************************************/
            using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
            {
                // simplified query, the real query uses UPDATE OUTPUT INSERTED
                const string sqlCommand = "SELECT [Columns] FROM dbo.[TABLE] WHERE [Status] = 'ready'";
                results = conn.Query({transaction: trans, sql: sqlCommand});
                trans.Commit();
            }
            DoAwesomeStuffWithTheResults(results, context);
        }
        WaitForWork();
    }
}
```

The SqlDependency related code:

```
private static ManualResetEvent _quitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

/// <summary>
/// Sets up a SqlDependency a doesn't return until it receives a Change notification
/// </summary>
private static void WaitForWork(){
    // in case we have dependency running we need to go a head and stop it first. 
    SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
    SqlDependency.Start(connString);

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Status] From dbo.[TABLE]", conn))
        {
            cmd.Notification = null;

            var dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate;

            conn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
    _quitEvent.WaitOne();
    SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
}
private static void dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    ((SqlDependency)sender).OnChange -= dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate;
    _quitEvent.Set();
}
```

I feel as though I've properly disposed of the context, its connection, and the transaction - before setting up the SqlDependency, but it would seem that isn't the case.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congrats on getting `SqlDependency` working (I'm not being sarcastic at all, many had failed at this).

Now is time to read [Creating a Query for Notification](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122(v=sql.105).aspx) topic on MSDN. You'll see the conditions under which queries are valid for notifications, including this requirement:

> The statement must not run under READ_UNCOMMITTED or SNAPSHOT isolation levels.

I wrote about [the basics of how `SqlDependency` works](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/), maybe will clear up some some misunderstandings. And, as a side node, since you're using Linq, you may be interested in [LinqToCache](https://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/), which provides a bridge between `Linq` queries and `SqlDependency`.

Another comment: do not `Start()` and `Stop()` your `SqlDependency` nilly-willy. You'll regret it soon. `Start()` is supposed to be called exactly once, during app startup, and `Stop()` exactly once during app shutdown (strictly speaking, is during appdomain loading and unloading).

Now, about your problem: the isolation level that matters is the one of the *notified query*. That means, the query on which you attach the subscription, *not* the query on which you do the `UPDATE` (I won't comment on the wisdom of doing UPDATE under dirty reads... or [the wisdom of using dirty reads for anything](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx)). As far as I can tell, the code you show should not post the query under read_uncommitted. After you issue a `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION ...` all subsequent transactions (ergo all statements) in that session will be under that isolation level. You close the connection (via the dispose of the DataContext) and then use a different connection. Unless ... you use connection pools. Welcome to the club of innocent victims :). [Connection pooling leaks isolation level changes across `Close()`/`Open()` boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9851415/105929). And that is your problem. There are some easy solutions:

- You can (must!) reset the isolation level explicitly after `Open()`
- You can use System.Transactions scopes (my recommendation). Mandatory reading: [using new TransactionScope() Considered Harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx)
- Do not use connection pooling.

And while we're talking, you need to read this also: [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

Comment: Haha, thanks; it was a tough journey! Are you saying that once I set up a transaction with `READ_UNCOMMITTED` all further statements are run under that Isolation Level? Or maybe I'm not disposing of the transaction properly (`using` should do it, no?)? (I'll admit I may be not fully understand some core SQL principles here)

Comment: Running the SqlDependency cmd in a transaction with an the IsolationLevel set to `IsolationLevel.Unspecified` did the trick!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'll read through everything and update my code appropriately. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code based on the tips Remus Rusanu gave in his answer:

```
private static string connString = "the connection string";
[MTAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
    // Start() is supposed to be called exactly once, during app startup
    // and Stop() exactly once during app shutdown:
    SqlDependency.Start(connString);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += delegate
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
    };

    while(true) // to infinity, and beyond.
    {
        using (var context = new LinqDataContext(connString))
        {
            var conn = context.Connection;
            // Connection pooling leaks isolation level changes across 
            // Close()/Open() boundaries, use TransactionScope to avoid this.
            using (var scope = CreateTransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
            {
                conn.Open();
                const string sqlCommand = "UPDATE TOP(1) [Table] SET [Status] = 'budy' OUTPUT INSERTED.[Column], */... MORE ...*/ WHERE [Status] = 'ready'";
                results = conn.Query(sqlCommand);
                scope.Complete();
            }
            DoAwesomeStuffWithTheResults(results, context);
        }
        WaitForWork();
    }
}
```

The SqlDependency related code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets up a SqlDependency and doesn't return until it receives 
/// a Change notification
/// </summary>
private static void WaitForWork(string connString)
{
    var changedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    OnChangeEventHandler dataChangedDelegate = (sender, e) => changedEvent.Set();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var scope = Databases.TransactionUtils.CreateTransactionScope())
        {
            conn.Open();
            var txtCmd = "SELECT [FileID] FROM dbo.[File] WHERE [Status] = 'ready'";
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(txtCmd, conn))
            {
                var dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                OnChangeEventHandler dataChangedDelegate = null;
                dataChangedDelegate = (sender, e) =>
                {
                    dependency.OnChange -= dataChangedDelegate;
                    changedEvent.Set();
                };
                dependency.OnChange += dataChangedDelegate;
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
    changedEvent.WaitOne();
    dependency.OnChange -= dependencyOnDataChangedDelegate;
}
```

New TransactionScope code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Using {the default} new TransactionScope Considered Harmful
/// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx
/// </summary>
private static TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope(System.Transactions.IsolationLevel isolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
{
    var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
    {
        IsolationLevel = isolationLevel,
        Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
    };
    return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions);
}
```