# SqlDependency triggers on uncommited data

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency

We have a import / bulk copy batch that runs in the middle of the night, something like

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)))
{
   //Delete existing
   ...
   //Bulk copy to temp table
   ...
   //Insert
   ...
   tx.Complete();
}
```

We also have a cache that uses SqlDependency. But it triggers allready on the Delete statement making the Cache empty for a few seconds between the delete nad the reinsert. Can I configure SqlDependency to only listen to commited data?

SqlDep. code

```
private IEnumerable<TEntity> RegisterAndFetch(IBusinessContext context)
{
    var dependency = new SqlDependency();
    dependency.OnChange += OnDependencyChanged;

    try
    {
        CallContext.SetData("MS.SqlDependencyCookie", dependency.Id);
        var refreshed = OnCacheRefresh(context, data.AsEnumerable());
        var result = refreshed.ToArray();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} - CacheChanged<{1}>: {2}", DateTime.Now, typeof(TEntity).Name, result.Length);

        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        CallContext.SetData("MS.SqlDependencyCookie", null);
    }
}
```

OnDependencyChanged basily calls above `RegisterAndFetch` method

**Query:**

```
protected override IEnumerable<BankHoliday> OnCacheRefresh(IBusinessContext context, IEnumerable<BankHoliday> currentData)
{
    var firstOfMonth = DateTime.Now.FirstDayOfMonth(); // <-- Must be a constant in the query
    return context.QueryOn<BankHoliday>().Where(bh => bh.Holiday >= firstOfMonth);
}
```

Comment: hmm you would expect your transaction scope to prevent this? is the delete correctly using the transaction scope?

Comment: ahh what query do you use for your dependancy notification? apparently there are issues

Comment: Well I guess the event should trigger, but the read should wait until the transaction is complete? See update for Query

Comment: no I mean the SqlDependency sql command. apparently there are restrictions on the type of select such as not using read uncommitted https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf4282bx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791152/sqldependency-subscription-not-working-when-using-isolationlevel-readuncommitted

Comment: Well the CMD is generated by EF, will check you links, thanks

Comment: why oh why do people still use EF?!

Comment: its the only certified ORM to use at this work place

Comment: I prefer raw SqlClient *old skool*

Comment: I have verified that its the Write side that causes the problem, I replaced the raw SQL with Entity framework and the SQLdep. is no longer doing dirty reads. So now I have to fidn out why the transaction is not working (EF is too slow for bulk copy)