# SqlConnection behaviour when changing isolation level in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

According to the remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms173763.aspx :

> Only one of the isolation level options can be set at a time, and it remains set for that connection until it is explicitly changed.

and according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx

> To minimize the cost of opening connections, ADO.NET uses an optimization technique called *connection pooling.*

Does this mean that if the `ISOLATION LEVEL` is changed in a stored procedure it carries over to other the next use of a connection? E.g.

```
var con1 = new SqlConnection("<THE CONNECTION STRING>"); 

// ...call stored procedure altering isolation level with:
// SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

con1.Close();

var con2 = new SqlConnection("<THE CONNECTION STRING>"); 
// ... will this connection potentially have the altered isolation level?
```

EDIT: Is there a simple way to check the isolation level used in a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to part A...

NO.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)...

> If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or
>   trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset
>   to the level in effect when the object was invoked. For example, if
>   you set REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the batch then calls a stored
>   procedure that sets the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, the isolation
>   level setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ when the stored procedure
>   returns control to the batc

Comment: This is good news for me, but is there a simple way to verify it? Also do I understand it correctly that if the isolation level is changed in SQL provided from the c# application (i.e. not in a stored proc.) then the connection's isolation level might change?

Comment: If you create the isolation level when you create a connection -- it's yours to keep. But there do appear to be possible leak issues if you aren't careful.  The following post covers this and how to check the level. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851415/sql-server-isolation-level-leaks-across-pooled-connections